# Single sign on with windows login

Tags: perl, authentication, active-directory, ldap, kerberos

Now, I am developing a single sign on, so that the windows login can be used to access the local website, I am writing the code in Perl, I have no experience in making something like this, since there will be some complicated steps such as; authenticate the user and the password with kerberos. i have no idea what to do, can anyone give me a tutorial link or want to share idea? or even teach me what to do?

Comment: What is your programming platform?

Comment: i am going to use perl, ive tried to find the tutorial, but seems no help: But, i think i need to use LDAP, and authenticate the username and password with kerberos, and there are still a ton complicated stuff to do. can you give or find me a tutorial? :)

Comment: Please change your question and write precisely what you want!

Comment: You still haven't written what you actually trying to do.

Comment: well, sorry, i need to make sso from windows login, so that that login and password can be used to login into local website, the website written in perl. Is it possible to make it?

Comment: So write: I want to access a Kerberos-protected URL with Perl.
Ist that correct?

Comment: yes, but i just dont how to start to build a single sign on with my windows login to also able to access my local web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about perl but I have done it using curl and urlconnect in java

Since you want SSO with windows login credentials, you wish to use your default credentials. This means that you do not need to use kerberos API directly in order to get a credential and convert it into a GSSAPI credential.

What you need is access to gssapi credentials. So you use:-

http://metacpan.org/pod/GSSAPI

The GSSAPI can be used to create context objects and pass around tokens needed for authentication. In case of SSO, just use the default credential (GSS_C_NO_CREDENTIAL) in the credential argument.

As far as url access goes, you need to find out how to use a url connection library in perl with the context object. This can be difficult and I have no idea how to do this. However you can alternately use libcurl with perl bindings. Libcurl uses GSS-API internally to do its job.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/perl/

You should build libcurl with GSS-Negotiate(MIT Kerberos) and SPNEGO(openssl and fbopenssl) if you wish to use libcurl for your work. This takes time and patience.

This should get you going. Remember, the resource being protected(or rather the protector program) must also use GSS-API(or equivalently SSPI since they are compatible)

Comment: can you send me your contact? because i think i need to consullt with you. if you can, please send me yours through ari.auhakim@gmail.com

Comment: i sent you a mail, check it. if this answer helps you, please upvote/accept it